# How can I paginate YouTube feed

Tags: youtube, rss

How can I paginate the YouTube feed using this URL: 
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=XXX

Thanks

Comment: The best option actually is using the Youtube API. See here the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination).

Comment: Did you find out?